# PHP map array data to HTML table while skipping some html table columns

Tags: php, html

Alo,

I have this array in php:

```
$data=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

I want to put it in html table that has the following structure (image)

[image]

The colored columns are to be skipped entirely. I have failed to do so but here is my attempt anyway:

```
$totalColumnsPerRow=8;
$skippableColumns=array(3,6,7,8);
$counter=1;
//loop the array now
$row="<tr>";
foreach($data as $val){
//do we need to start a new row or not?
 if ($counter==$totalColumnsPerRow){
 //close open row and create a new one.
 $counter=1;
 $row.="</tr><tr>":
  }

 //show I skip the current column or not?
 if(in_array($counter,$skippableColumns)){
 //skip column then add current value
 $row.="<td></td>";
 $row.="<td>$val</td>";
 }
 else{
 $row.="<td>$val</td>";
  }
 $counter++;
}
```

That gives me the following table structure. If it had successfully skipped the rows, a new row would have started with value 5.

[image]

Here is a [PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ed5p-zwyx)

Any idea on how to like pause the loop and use it in usable column? Is my approach practical?

Comment: try to add separate loops for each row

Comment: It looks like it will be very slow process but lemme give it a shot still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code. Please try the following. Added comments for better understanding.

```
<table border="1" width="600px">
<tr>
<td>A</td><td>B</td><td>ABT</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>CDT</td><td>ACT</td><td>TTT</td>
</tr>

<?php

$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$totalColumnsPerRow = 8;
$skippableColumns = array(3,6,7,8);

$table = '<tr>';
$lastIndex = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= $totalColumnsPerRow; $i++) { // Per column

    if(in_array($i, $skippableColumns)) { // Skipping coulmn value
        $table .= '<td></td>';
    } else { // Adding coulmn value
        $table .= '<td>'.$data[$lastIndex].'</td>';
        $lastIndex++; // Incrementing data index
    }

    if($i == $totalColumnsPerRow) { // Last column
        $table .= '</tr>'; // Ending row

        if($lastIndex <= count($data) -1) { // Data left
            $table .= '<tr>'; // Starting new row

            $i = 0; // Resetting so in the next increment it will become 1
        }
    }
}

echo $table;
?>
```

Output is
[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Lemme see other suggestions and compare. Thanks man. So clear and efficient as well.

Comment: @NieSelam Glad I could helped you

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to recheck within the same loop (using the same $val data) with the seldom used, much maligned [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) control. Minimal changes to your existing code.

```
foreach($data as $val){
    //we'll come back here to decide on skip or write of next row when a skippable is encountered
    //this keeps us locked onto the same $val until it is written out
    recheck: 
    //do we need to start a new row or not?
    if ($counter==$totalColumnsPerRow){
    //close open row and create a new one.
        $counter=1;
        $row.="</tr><tr>";
    }

    //show I skip the current column or not?
    if(in_array($counter,$skippableColumns)){
    //skip column then add current value
        $row.="<td></td>";
        $counter++;
        goto recheck;
    //   $row.="<td>$val</td>";
    }
    else{
        $row.="<td>$val</td>";
    }
    $counter++;
}
```